# how to runtimely show call stack in system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

currently i use this way, when run time error happens, vcs will print call stack. It is very low effecient. Is there a better way?

```
function void anyFunctionIWouldLikeToSeeCallStack();
uvm_object a;
// a == null
a.print();
endfunction;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VCS, it's `$stack()`

but it's only about 8 levels of the stack, and I don't think that's configurable

Answer (score 2):

Cadence incisive (ncsim) has a $stacktrace system task that you can call.  I wouldn't be surprised if the other vendors have a similar thing.

Comment: Same $stacktrace in Modelsim/Questa.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of thing a simulator usually provides while setting breakpoints. After reaching a certain breakpoint your simulation will stop and you'll be able to run a simulator specific command to print the call stack or you'll have the call stack shown in some GUI window.

You'll have to look up in the VCS documentation how this is done exactly.

Answer (score 0):

in RivieraPro, the command is $callstack(). There are a few options you can pass to configure the output.

See the documentation:
R-PRO: User's Guide | SystemVerilog Simulation | SystemVerilog Non-standard Extensions | $callstack system function